# PIC18 microseconds counter

Tags: pic, timer, counter

I want to count microseconds between timer's ON/OFF. My FOSC is 48 MHz.
I figured out timer1 would need to be initialized like (I'm programming in mplab):

```
// Freq = 1000000.00 Hz - Period = 0.000001 seconds
T1CONbits.T1CKPS1 = 0;   // Prescaler rate
T1CONbits.T1CKPS0 = 0;   // 1:1

T1CONbits.T1OSCEN = 1;   // Oscillator enable control bit 1 = on
T1CONbits.T1SYNC = 1;    // External Clock Input Synchronization Control bit...1 = Do not synchronize
T1CONbits.TMR1CS = 0;    // Timer1 Clock Source Select bit...0 = Internal clock (FOSC/4)
T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;    // disable timer
TMR1H = 255;             // preset for MSB register
TMR1L = 253;             // preset for LSB register
```

And later timing:

```
T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
... some work ...
T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;
us = (TMR1H<<8) + (TMR1L);
```

It's not working correctly. Probably because of timer's overflow. How do i deal with this correctly?

Comment: How long does the code run? One possibility instead of trying to deal with overflow might be to just reset the timer value. But some extra detail on the overall result you're after would be good.

Comment: I have measured code and it takes 300-40000 us to run. So I need to get these values from my timer

Comment: Try setting `TMR1L` and `TMR1H` to zero before starting it and see how it goes. It's been a while since I've done much with PIC timers other than re-using existing code so I'm not sure if your other configuration code is correct or not off the top of my head but that should do the trick if everything else is OK.

Comment: Are you expecting to have a 1 us clock? You have set prescale at 1:1 and selected internal clock (FOSC/4).  For a 48 Mhz FOSC, you will need to divide your result by 12 if you want the time in microseconds.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with overflow (and you need to measure up to 40000 us as you indicate above), you could use 1:8 prescale which would clock every 2/3 us.

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting 1us clock that behaves like a counter. Thank you for FOSC info, it'll come handy later. Anyway, if my FOSC/4 = 12MHz and I set TMR1 preload to 65533, i should get my interrupt period at 1us? Doesn't get that preloaded value lost if i reset it to 0 before enabling the timer?

Comment: The preload just sets the current value of the timer. It has no effect on the clock period. It would probably be best to set it to zero. You are confusing using the timer to generate a clock with using it for counting clock cycles. You can't use the same timer for both at the same time (other than the prescale provided).

Comment: If you are thinking of generating a 1 us interrupt and running a software counter in the interrupt ... don't.  It would interfere with whatever you were trying to time; and with a CPU clock of FOSC/4, that's only 12 instructions max!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things don't make sense.  Timer 1 has no period register, only a prescaler that can do powers of 2 from 1 to 8.  You can't therefore time µs directly.  The oscillator of 48 MHz means a 12 MHz instruction clock, so you would have to divide by 12 to get µs.  However, you gave no justification for why you need to measure µs exactly, so we can assume you can use something else roughly in that range and scale later if it really matters.

Since you seem to be trying to measure code cycles, I'd set up the prescaler for 8, which is the largest you can do anyway.  That will increment the timer at 12 MHz / 8 = 1.5 MHz rate, which is every 667 ns.  The maximum interval you can time is 65535 counts, which is 43.7 ms.  If you try to time something longer than that, information will be lost due to timer wrap-around.

You have no comments in your code indicating what you think each setting does.  Shame on you!  I'm not going to spend a lot of time diagnosing irresponsibly written code.  However, I happened to notice you have the timer 1 oscillator enabled.  Without comments we can't tell what you think the purpose of that is, or whether you really intended that or not.

Comment: Sorry, added comments to my code. Thanks for clearing some things up, will try to implement them.